# javascript calculator on asp.net content page. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp.net content page and I need to write a calculator inside(?) it.

```
<%@ Page Title="Calculator" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Calculator.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.Calculator" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent"></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<!-- calculator code here -->
</asp:Content>
```

I have a html page with a simple javascript calculator:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function addvalue(arg1) {
        Calc.Input.value += arg1;
    }

</script>

<form action="#" name="Calc">

<table style="width: 160px" border="2">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <input id="Text1" type="text" maxlength=16 name="Input" style="width:98%" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 40px">
            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="1" onclick="addvalue('1')" /></td>
        <td style="width: 40px">
            <input id="Button2" type="button" value="2" onclick="addvalue('2')" /></td>
        <td style="width: 40px">
            <input id="Button3" type="button" value="3" onclick="addvalue('3')" /></td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button7" type="button" value="+" onclick="addvalue(' + ')" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="Button4" type="button" value="4" onclick="addvalue('4')" /></td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button5" type="button" value="5" onclick="addvalue('5')" /></td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button6" type="button" value="6" onclick="addvalue('6')" /></td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button8" type="button" value="-" onclick="addvalue(' - ')" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="Button9" type="button" value="7" onclick="addvalue('7')" /></td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button10" type="button" value="8" onclick="addvalue('8')" /></td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button11" type="button" value="9" onclick="addvalue('9')" /></td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button12" type="button" value="*" onclick="addvalue('*')" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="Button13" type="button" value="C" onclick="Calc.Input.value=null" /></td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button14" type="button" value="0" onclick="addvalue('0')" /></td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button15" type="button" value="=" onclick="Calc.Input.value = eval(Calc.Input.value)" /></td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button16" type="button" value="/" onclick="addvalue(' / ')" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to adapt this code for using with an asp.net content page. How can I do it ?

I know that asp.net is server-side technology and javascript is a client-side. But I don't know how to use one inside another =\

Comment: Yes of course it is possible, what have you tried?

Comment: mcpDESIGNS, I need to move this js code to asp.net. I cant' get a working code unfortunately..

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, only put the `JS` or `Jquery` script inside the content looks the code below:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<table style="width: 160px" border="2">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <input id="Text1" type="text" maxlength=16 name="Input" style="width:98%" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 40px">
            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="1" onclick="addvalue('1')" /></td>
        <td style="width: 40px">
            <input id="Button2" type="button" value="2" onclick="addvalue('2')" /></td>
        <td style="width: 40px">
            <input id="Button3" type="button" value="3" onclick="addvalue('3')" /></td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button7" type="button" value="+" onclick="addvalue(' + ')" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="Button4" type="button" value="4" onclick="addvalue('4')" /></td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button5" type="button" value="5" onclick="addvalue('5')" /></td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button6" type="button" value="6" onclick="addvalue('6')" /></td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button8" type="button" value="-" onclick="addvalue(' - ')" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="Button9" type="button" value="7" onclick="addvalue('7')" /></td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button10" type="button" value="8" onclick="addvalue('8')" /></td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button11" type="button" value="9" onclick="addvalue('9')" /></td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button12" type="button" value="*" onclick="addvalue('*')" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="Button13" type="button" value="C" onclick="Calc.Input.value=null" /></td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button14" type="button" value="0" onclick="addvalue('0')" /></td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button15" type="button" value="=" onclick="Calc.Input.value = eval(Calc.Input.value)" /></td>
        <td>
            <input id="Button16" type="button" value="/" onclick="addvalue(' / ')" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function addvalue(arg1) {
        Calc.Input.value += arg1;
    }

</script>
</asp:Content>
```

I hope that helps

Comment: Freak_Droid, thanks for an answer! It doesn't work unfortunately. I press buttons and nothing appears in input textbox.